# Preventing untagged containers from running on specific nodes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have some nodes in my swarm where I want to only allow containers with a specific tag to be scheduled. Any container without that specific tag must not be scheduled on these nodes.

OpenShift has this functionality in [taints and tolerations](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/nodes/scheduling/nodes-scheduler-taints-tolerations.html).

> A taint allows a node to refuse pod to be scheduled unless that pod has a matching toleration.

Is there something similar in Swarm that I haven't been able find, or some way to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Swarm mode has the concept of constraints, which is the inverse of taints and tolerations. With constraints, you add labels to your swarm nodes. And you then use those labels with constraints on a service to permit or deny a workload from running on a specific node. The inverse part is each service needs to specify constraints to exclude specific nodes, the scheduling model includes all nodes by default regardless of their labels.